# ASP.NET GridView - Click on a cell, edit, and update SQL Server database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am working on an ASP.NET web application in Visual Studio 2017. On one of my `.aspx` web pages, I have a GridView that displays a table from SQL Server.

I am trying to create controls where a user on the client side can click on a cell in the GridView, the cell turns into a textbox, the user can put in a new value, and upon leaving the cell or pressing enter, the GridView and SQL Server table update to show the new value.

In addition when a cell is clicked, a delete row button is generated. If the delete row button is clicked, the row containing the selected cell is deleted from the GridView and the SQL Server table.

Lastly, there needs to be an add row button at the bottom of the GridView. Clicking the add row button creates a new row in the GridView, the first cell of the row turns into a textbox, the user can put in a value, and upon leaving the cell or pressing enter, the GridView and SQL Server table update to show the new row.

I dynamically generate the GridView with `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` and bind the GridView in code behind. If possible, I would like to keep it this way and not hardcode the SQL Server table columns into the GridView.

Here is my current markup for my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewJobList" runat="server"
     GridLines="None" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Names="Verdana" 
     Font-Size="9pt" EmptyDataText=" "
     OnRowCommand="GridViewJobList_RowCommand"  
     OnRowDataBound="GridViewJobList_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="CellClick" Visible="False"></asp:ButtonField>
    </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                         VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
    <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle Wrap="False" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                 HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="True" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                 HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="True" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is my current C# code behind:

```
private static string sQuery, sTable;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
            sQuery = null;
            sTable = "JobList";
            sQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + sTable + "]";
            GridViewSQL();
    }
}

private void GridViewSQL()
{
        try
        {
            GridViewJobList.DataSource = SQLDB.DBData(sQuery);
            GridViewJobList.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception openex) { MessageBox(openex.Message); }
}

protected void GridViewJobList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton _singleClickButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        string _jsSingle = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_singleClickButton, "");

        // Add events to each editable cell
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < e.Row.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
        {
            // Add the column index as the event argument parameter
            string js = _jsSingle.Insert(_jsSingle.Length - 2, columnIndex.ToString());
            // Add this javascript to the onclick Attribute of the cell
            e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Attributes["onclick"] = js;
            // Add a cursor style to the cells
            e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Attributes["style"] += "cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;";
        }
    }
}

protected void GridViewJobList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "CellClick")
    {
        int selectedRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        int selectedColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString());

        var vSelectedCell = GridViewJobList.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[selectedColumnIndex];
    }
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow r in GridViewJobList.Rows)
    {
        if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < r.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(r.UniqueID + "$ctl00", columnIndex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    base.Render(writer);
}

private void MessageBox(string sError) //Pop up MessageBox for error messages in web browser
{
    string sScript = "alert(\"" + sError + "\");";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", sScript, true);
}
```

I am a novice programmer and I have been trying the figure out how to do this for over a week with no luck. I assume the solution is a combination of ASP, C#, and JavaScript/jQuery. I am comfortable at making a SQL Server connection in C# and using a SQL command to update a table in SQL Server. I am struggling with the JavaScript/jQuery client side controls and getting the correct information from the GridView in the C# code behind to use for my SQL commands.

I have been able to select a GridView cell onclick with this example: http://www.dotnetlogix.com/Article/aspnet/80/How-to-make-GridView-Individual-Cells-Selectable.html

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your question is entirely too broad. But you really need to be careful with your queries. Building up a string and executing is incredibly dangerous as it exposes your system to sql injection. Your code as posted is not vulnerable but the pattern your demonstrate is a textbook example of the vulnerability.

Comment: I am using SQL Parameters for client side inputs to prevent SQL Injection.

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@string", sString);

Comment: Since you don't seem to be using stored procedures you might take a peek at this article. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ Sometimes the incorrect datatype will be interpreted which can drive you crazy.

Comment: I had no idea I could do that. I'll add that to my code. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.